# Random Variable with Distribution Function being uncontinous in points dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory

I am supposed to find a random variable which has a distribution function which has uncontinous points which lie dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $q_n$ be a counting of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. the sequence $(q_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ goes through all the rational numbers). I have this distribution function:

$$F(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{1}_{[q_n, \infty)}(x) \cdot 2^{-n}$$

This is a distribution function as wanted because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But is there any way to actually write out the random variable? Because that's what I am really supposed to find, not its distribution function. Or should I just argue that this uniquely identifies the random variable?

Comment: Say $X$ is decided by $P(X=q_n)=2^{-n}$...

Comment: Unless the problem specifically states to specify $X(\omega)$ for $\omega\in\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is some sample space, the distribution function should suffice.